# Are there Bond ETF’s that don’t go down?

Tags: investing, etf, starting-out-investing, bond-etf

I would like to put some percentage of my money in an investment that only goes up, even if it goes up only by a small amount.  One way to do this would be to put my money in a bank account, but I’d like a higher rate of return than that.  Is there an investment which has a very low chance of going down, but which offers a higher rate of return than a bank?  Preferably an ETF.

I thought Bond ETF’s would do that.  But when I look at supposedly safe Bond ETF’s like [this](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/performance/bsv), they seem to often go down.  Apparently when interest rates go up the prices of the bonds in such bond funds go down, and that causes the value of the fund to go down.

Are there Bond ETF’s which only expose you to (low) default risk and not to interest rate risk?  Or some other kind of ETF which has a very small chance of going down?

Comment: **Everybody** wants an investment which never goes down, but that pays more than the bank.  **It doesn't exist.**

Comment: @RonJohn What about something that rarely goes down?  Something that offers a slightly better return than a bank in exchange for slightly more risk?

Comment: You could always buy individual bonds...

Comment: Of course, you'd have to hold them until maturity.

Comment: @RonJohn Well, I want an ETF that does that.  I want an investment which I can sell at any time and which has a low chance of me having to sell it at a lower price than what I bought it for.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So you are looking for an ETF version of VMMXX ?

Comment: "Well, I want an ETF that does that."  So do I.  So does @BenVoigt.  But there's a reason our money isn't in these unicorn ETFs: **they don't exist**.

Comment: @BenVoigt he's wanting something that will yield **more** than 1.7%, or even the 2% CDs at online banks.

Comment: @RonJohn: Well, for this purpose I use JPST.  It isn't quite as stable as VMMXX, but on the risk vs reward axis it's very very close.  And it *is* an ETF.  Now, I would prefer to just use an FDIC-insured bank savings account.  But a savings account doesn't meet my brokerage account minimum balance requirement... JPST does.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's SEC yield is 2.01%, with a 0.18% expense ration.  Why shouldn't I put the money in Ally Savings or 12 month CDs?

Comment: @RonJohn: Because 2.01% is higher than 1.6%?  It's a higher interest rate than Ally Savings and no-penalty CDs, and greater liquidity than Ally ordinary CDs.  Remember the 2.01% is after the 0.18% is already deducted.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's why you ladder them. :)

Comment: Principal-protected structured products might be of interest https://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/07/structured_products.asp if the desire is to gain exposure to potential market upside but be protected from downside.  I don't know enough about what's available in the US to write more than that though, and they probably wouldn't meet a requirement to be able to exit at any time.

Comment: @timday It looks like they have been turned into an ETF: https://www.barrons.com/articles/structured-notes-can-new-etfs-make-them-actually-work-for-investors-1543612302

Comment: @Keshav Yes I'd noticed http://www.innovatoretfs.com/define/ and thought they were an interesting development (is there nothing that won't eventually get wrapped up in ETF form?).  So far as I could tell none of them satisfy your desire to protect the principal sum though... there's just a bit of a threshold - the "downside buffer" - before market losses start to bite, if things do turn bad enough.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're wanting to avoid, which you called "interest rate risk", has the formal name of **duration risk**.  It's actually calculated as (effective duration * interest rate volatility), but it's named after the duration rather than the interest rate.

That also tells you how to minimize it.  Choose a fund with an extremely low effective duration.  The one I use is [JPST](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/bats/jpst/portfolio).

Any fund in the same category could serve, such as BIL, ICSH, or GSY.  The category name "Ultrashort Bond" sounds like it is inverse (short) leverage (ultra) on bonds... but it isn't.  Rather it is long on bonds with ultrashort duration.

ETFdb actually calls these ["Money Market ETFs"](https://etfdb.com/etfdb-category/money-market/)

---

In addition to (very low) default risk, the premium/discount is affected by demand.  When the market is all "flight to safety", demand for low risk ETFs is up and there will be a price premium vs net asset value.  When the market is hot and investors have the fear of missing out, demand for low risk is down, and there will be a discount vs NAV.  This is probably somewhat correlated with interest rate volatility.  But due to ETF efficient price arbitrage, demand only affects the price by a couple pennies (or equivalently, about 1-2 week's returns).

If you look at the price chart, this is the noise.  The big sawtooth signal is payout of dividends monthly.

[image]

Comment: One can infer from the graph that if you reinvest the dividends in the same instrument that you'd see fairly uniform returns.

Comment: Does this give a higher return than a bank account?  And can we put a number on how big the default risk is?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes, higher return than bank accounts (with the exception of specialty accounts with velocity requirements).  No, I have no idea how to quantify that risk.  If the housing bubble taught us anything it is that bond ratings are meaningless.  Not all bonds are equally risky but you can't trust the rating to tell them apart.